# Comparing user input to csv value

Tags: python-3.x

So I have this csv data

```
Medium narrow body, £8, 2650, 180, 8
Large narrow body, £7, 5600, 220, 10
Medium wide body, £5, 4050, 406, 14
```

The data I need to use are the numbers all the way on the right which have been given a fieldname 'first_class' and second from right given field name 'Capacity'
and I have made this code

```
    import csv
    def menu():
        print ("""
             1.Enter airport details
             2.Enter flight details
             3.Enter price plan and calculate profit
             4. Clear data
             5.Quit
                """)
if b == '2':
        a1 = input('Enter the type of aircraft: ')
        airplane_info = open('airplane.csv', 'r')
        csvreader = csv.DictReader(airplane_info,delimiter = ',',fieldnames=('Body_type','Running_cost','Max_flight','Capacity','first_class'))
        for row in csvreader:
            if row['Body_type'] == a1:
                print(row)
    if row['Body_type'] != a1:
        print('Wrong aircraft type')
        flag = False
    else:
        d1 = input('Enter number of first class seats on the aircraft')
        if d1 != 0:
```

(That flag was sending user back to the options menu ignore it)
Now I need to use the aircraft type that the user input and use it's 'first_class' fieldname with the amount of first class seats the user enters. Let's say if the user input an aircraft type 'Medium wide body'. It has 14 first class seats. When the user is asked to enter first class seats and ends up entering lower then 14 an error message should pop up. How would I do it? Would I input the csv data into an array and then use it for the comparison?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example using Pandas library. You will need to install it:

```
pip install --user pandas
```

Using pandas you can parse the csv into a dataframe object and then work on it as you desire:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('airplane.csv', names=["Body_type", "Running_cost", "Max_flight", "Capacity", "first_class"])  
a1 = input('Enter the type of aircraft: ')
if a1 in df.Body_type.values:
    body = df[df.Body_type == a1]
    d1 = int(input('Enter number of first class seats on the aircraft: '))
    if d1 < body["first_class"].values[0]:
        print("Error")
    # ...
else:
    print('Wrong aircraft type')
```